# C++ constructor: which exception type should I throw when malloc fails to allocate memory

Tags: c++, error-handling, constructor, malloc, throw

So, imagine I have this code:

```
typedef struct Point {
    float x;
    float y;
} Point;

class Foo {
    private:
        Point * p;
    public:
        Foo () {
            this->p = (Point *) malloc(sizeof(Point));
            if (this->p == NULL) {
                // throw exception_malloc_fail;
            }
        }
};
```

Which kind of exception should I throw once malloc fails allocating memory inside a constructor?

In this kind of situation, I cannot simply return `false` or `NULL`. So a `throw` statement should be the way to go.

However, I cannot find the correct type of exception to throw. Should I just throw a default exception? Or is there one appropriate for this kind of situation?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc

Comment: Do you have a reason for using `malloc` instead of `new`, which will automatically throw?  `malloc`, which will not call constructors, is typically used in a different language that doesn't support constructors.

Comment: The `typedef struct Point` makes me think that this is someone coming from C and the `malloc` just tagged along.

Comment: Better yet, avoid allocation at all and use `Point p` instead of a pointer.

Comment: You're writing a very strange mixture of C and C++. Pick one.

Comment: @OlafDietsche, I didn't want to use that because, as I do not know how classes work out of scope, I have some fears about using the stack to store data that might probably vanish if the class object goes out of scope at some point. I had this problem when using Gtk once with C structs. It's weird and very situational, but it happened and caused some headaches to find it out.

Comment: @DrewDormann, As I am a better C programmer than a C++ one, I still prefer to use malloc over new. Besides that, I do not know how much expensive it is to create a class instance vs allocate memory using malloc, for something as simple as a point. In my eyes, it costs less memory and it is faster to use malloc, though I need to make some research about it to check if it's true.

Comment: "_I do not know how classes work out of scope_" - objects are destroyed when they go out of scope. Since you haven't implemented [everything needed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to hold a raw pointer your class is unsafe. It will also leak memory when a `Foo` instance goes out of scope. "_I still prefer to use malloc over new_" - What you get with `malloc`  is not an object, you only get memory. Accessing `Point` members in that memory makes your program have undefined behavior.

Comment: _"In my eyes, it costs less memory and it is faster to use malloc"_ @CarlHR Your eyes deceive you. `new` will not cost any more than `malloc` will (in fact, often `new` is written in terms of `malloc`). However `new` is actually part of the C++ **language** and starts the lifetime of a new object; `malloc` is not, and will instead cause undefined behavior if you have an object that is trivial. It's not a matter of personal preference; it's a very significant matter of *right and wrong*. If you're unfamiliar with it, I highly advise you become familiar with it

Comment: It's also really important to realize that in many cases the C++ compiler can actually optimize away unnecessary calls to `new` and `delete` if it sees the lifetime of the object as bound to a specific scope. This is possible because the language speaks of `new` in terms of object lifetime. `malloc` and `free`, on the other hand, are harder to prove to the optimizer -- since they are _library calls_. If you add that to C++20 with `new`/`delete` being `constexpr`, then you can actually have far better performance with `new`/`delete` than possible with `malloc`/`free`

Comment: (Just to clarify my first comment: I'm not saying `malloc` is not part of C++ -- just that `malloc` doesn't start an object lifetime. I could have worded that better)

Comment: @CarlHR to put it very succinctly: `malloc` is never better than `new`, and can be more dangerous.  And `new Point` is arguably much more readable than `(Point *) malloc(sizeof(Point))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most appropriate exception would be to throw [`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc); however it is strongly discouraged to use `malloc` unless you have a good reason to -- and so I would advise against throwing this explicitly.

If you absolutely *need* heap memory, you should be using `new`/`delete` -- which will automatically invoke constructors/destructors, start/end object lifetimes, and will throw a `std::bad_alloc` when out of memory for you. `std::malloc` will result in undefined behavior for any non-trivial types because it doesn't formally start an object's lifetime.

Better yet, [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) has been out for over **ten years**, so use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and, if you have [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), use [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) so you don't even *need* `new` directly. `unique_ptr` will prevent memory leaks by ensuring that `delete` is called on the allocated pointer if the pointer is not-null.

This would now look like:

```cpp
#include <memory>

// Note: 'typedef struct' does nothing in C++ -- there is no need for it
struct Point {
    float x;
    float y;
};

class Foo {
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Point> p;
    public:
        Foo () 
          : p{std::make_unique<Point>()}
        {

        }
};
```

---

Aside from the above answer: You shouldn't really use heap memory unless you really have a need for objects with dynamic lifetime. In the code you provided, it looks like it may be more appropriate to just hold the `Point` by value anyway:

```cpp
class Foo {
    private:
        Point p;
    public:
        Foo () 
          : p{} // no allocation needed
        {

        }
};
```